# Materials for SICP with python?

Tags: python, sicp

I want to try out SICP with Python.

Can any one point to materials (video.article...) that teaches Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs in **python**.

Currently learning from SICP videos of Abelson, Sussman, and Sussman.

Comment: I recommend learning LISP. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't think there is a complete set of materials, [this](http://www.codepoetics.com/wiki/index.php?title=Topics:SICP_in_other_languages) is the best I know.

If you are up to generating the material yourself, a bunch of us plan to work through SICP collectively [at](http://hn-sicp.pbwiki.com/). I know at least one guy will be using Haskell, so you will not be alone in pursuing an alternative route.

Comment: +1 for the codepoetics post before plugging your own website.  :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with plugging your own site if it answers the question and adds value to the discussion.

Comment: http://www.codepoetics.com/wiki/index.php?title=Topics:SICP_in_other_languages is 404. Anyone knows where can one find them elsewhere?

Answer (score 10):

I think this would be great for you, [CS61A SICP](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa11/61a-python/content/www/index.html) in Python by Berkeley

[sicp-python](https://github.com/dongchongyubing/sicp-python) code at Github

Comment: Your GitHub links are both dead :(

Comment: I think the first one https://github.com/dongchongyubing/sicp-python, sorry for the second.

Answer (score 9):

A direct translation of SICP in Python would make no sense - Scheme and Python are way too different. But there are a couple similar books in Python. The first that comes to mind is "thinking like a computer scientist". You'll find more informations about available material here:
http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy/

Comment: I thought SICP was about programming not about Scheme, I know Scheme is used to put across the theory.

Comment: SICP is really about functional programming, and Python is an imperative object-oriented language. Definitly not the same way to design your programs.

Comment: Actually Python has a lot of influence from Lisp and functional languages (http://twit.tv/show/floss-weekly/11) and it has certainly a lot of tools to support functional programming (http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/functional.html).

Comment: @mcepl: Yes Python has first-class functions, (restricted) closures, (very restricted) lambdas and borrowed a couple idioms from Lisp and Haskell, but it's still a statement-based imperative language at heart and trying to do proper FP in Python will only feel frustratring at best.

Answer (score 4):

here is what you need - http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa11/61a-python/content/www/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but thought this might be useful for someone.

http://composingprograms.com/

> In the tradition of SICP, this text focuses on methods for
>   abstraction, programming paradigms, and techniques for managing the
>   complexity of large programs. These concepts are illustrated primarily
>   using the Python 3 programming language.
>   ...
>   Composing Programs is authored and maintained by John DeNero.
>   The text was originally published as lecture notes for CS 61A at UC
>   Berkeley and is based upon the Structure and Interpretation of
>   Computer Programs by Harold Abelson and Gerald Jay Sussman.