# Translating SICP solution from Scheme to Python

Tags: python, lisp, scheme, sicp

I have this solution for SICP code in Lisp:

```lisp
 ;; ex 1.11. Iterative implementation 

 (define (f n) 
   (define (iter a b c count) 
     (if (= count 0) 
       a 
       (iter b c (+ c (* 2 b) (* 3 a)) (- count 1)))) 
   (iter 0 1 2 n))
```

I don't really know how Lisp works; I understand a few thing here, but it's still hard for me to translate it to Python. For example, I don't know why `a` is written below `if`.  How could this code be translated to Python or C++?
(the function have to be iterative and not recursive)

Comment: In the future, please do at least a _little_ research on your questions before asking.  The second result from Google when searching for [sicp python translation](https://www.google.com/search?q=sicp+python#q=sicp+python+translation&safe=off) is [SICP Translation - Python Code - Chapter #1](http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/pl/sicp_python_01.html).  That doesn't include an _explanation_ of the code, so I've still posted an answer below, but if you can already read Python, you should be able to use the Python code to figure out what the Lisp code is doing.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [Materials for SICP with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/432637/1281433).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to think about the translation. One would be to write a literal, straight translation without respecting Python's idioms and conventions - it will look like this:

```
def f(n):
    def iter(a, b, c, count):
        if count == 0:
            return a
        else:
            return iter(b, c, 2*b + 3*a + c, count-1)
    return iter(0, 1, 2, n)
```

The other way is to write the code in a Pythonic fashion such that it respects the target language's conventions and makes use of its iteration mechanisms:

```
def f(n):
    a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
    for count in range(n):
        a, b, c = b, c, 2*b + 3*a + c
    return a
```

By the way, the second version will be faster, and won't  have a problem with an stack overflow error (Python is *not* optimized for recursion!). It's irrelevant that in the recursive version `count` goes from `n` to `0` and in the loop version `count` goes from `0` to `n`, because anyway the value of `count` is not being used for anything besides iterating a given number of times.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at that code:

```
;; ex 1.11. Iterative implementation 

(define (f n) 
  (define (iter a b c count) 
    (if (= count 0) 
      a 
      (iter b c (+ c (* 2 b) (* 3 a)) (- count 1)))) 
  (iter 0 1 2 n))
```

The first thing to note here is that *two* functions are being defined.  One is `f`, and the other is `iter`.  `iter` is a helper function, and is intended to be used only by `f` (since it's defined *inside* of `f`. There's no reason that you can't actually separate the two definitions, though, into:

```
(define (iter a b c count) 
  (if (= count 0) 
    a 
    (iter b c (+ c (* 2 b) (* 3 a)) (- count 1))))

(define (f n) 
  (iter 0 1 2 n))
```

In Lisps, the syntax `(frob bar1 bar2 ...)` means that you're calling the function `frob` with arguments `bar1`, `bar2`, `...`.  So the definition of `f`

```
(define (f n) 
  (iter 0 1 2 n))
```

should be relatively clear.  You're defining a function `f` that takes a single argument `n`, and then you're calling the function `iter` with four arguments, `0`, `1`, `2`, and `n`.  So what does `iter` do?

```
(define (iter a b c count) 
  (if (= count 0) 
    a 
    (iter b c (+ c (* 2 b) (* 3 a)) (- count 1))))
```

`iter` takes four arguments.  First, it checks whether `count` is `0`.  If it is, then `iter` returns `a`.  Otherwise, `iter` calls itself recursively with `b`, `c`. `(+ c (* 2 b) (* 3 a))` and `(- count 1)` and value that the recursive call returns is returned.  Base on the description of Lisp syntax above, you should be able to tell that `(+ c (* 2 b) (* 3 a))` is just the mathematical expression *c + 2b + 3a*, and that `(- count 1)` is just *count-1*.

The trickiest part about all of this, I suppose, is knowing that `if` takes three arguments:  the first is the test expression; the second is the "then" part, also called the consequent; and the third is the "else" part, also called the alternative.  Unlike some other languages where `if` is just used to conditionally execute some statements, `(if ...)` returns a *value* in Lisp, and the value is either the value of the the consequent or the value of the alternative, depending on whether the value of the test was true or false.

With this description, you should be able to write up a counterpart in any programming language that you are familiar with.

Of course, once you understand all that, you might do well to read some of [Chris Rathman's translation of SICP code into Python](http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/pl/sicp_python_01.html), which includes a translation of this the code from Exercise 1.11:

```py
# Exercise 1.11
def f(n):
   if n < 3:
      return n
   else:
      return f(n-1) + 2*f(n-2) + 3*f(n-3)
def f_iter(a, b, c, count):
   if count == 0:
      return c
   else:
      return f_iter(a + 2*b + 3*c, a, b, count-1)
def f(n):
   return f_iter(2, 1, 0, n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is basically how iter looks like in C

```
int iter (int a, int b, int c, int count)
{
    if( count == 0 )
       return a;
    else
       return iter(b, c, c + (2 * b) + (3 * a), count - 1);
}
```

Every expression in Scheme evaluates to a value thus it's implicit return. The `if` returns whatever the branch is run and iter return whatever the if returns and so on.

Without knowing for sure this looks like a recursive sequence that refer to the 3 previous numbers to calculate the next that has been made iterated to constant stack in Scheme. Be aware that Python wont tail call optimize this and C++ and C probably needs special compiler options and a capable compiler to do it.

Comment: or a `while`-based explicit loop re-write. :)